# Turn a bytes-like string into actual bytes in Python

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, arrays

Is there a build-in function in python 3 to let me get `b` from `a`?

```
a = '\\xe9\\x82\\xa3'
b = b'\xe9\x82\xa3'
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`unicode-escape`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#text-encodings) encoding:

```
>>> a = '\\xe9\\x82\\xa3'
>>> a.encode().decode('unicode-escape').encode('latin1')
b'\xe9\x82\xa3'
```

---

```
>>> import codecs
>>> codecs.decode(a, 'unicode-escape').encode('latin1')
b'\xe9\x82\xa3'
```